# AngularJS's $httpBackend - how to configure?

Tags: testing, angularjs, angular-scenario

I'm making an angular app and am running end-to-end tests on them. I need to run a `$httpBackend` instance for some of my tests, but I can't figure out how to do it. Currently my code looks like

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Controller', function () {
    $http.post('/register/reg').success(function () console.log('yay'););
\\ things...
myTestingApp = angular.module('myTestingApp', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
myTestingApp.run(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/\/register\/reg.*/').respond(200);
});
```

then I just navigate to `runner.html` and run my tests. All of my other tests are seen by Karma, but this is not. What's going on?

Comment: Is it working under runner.html?  If not, are you bootstrapping your application with the myTestingApp module, i.e. ng-app="myTestingApp"?

Comment: @KarlZilles I'm bootstrapping, yes. It's also running on runner.html though.